# Using Predicate in Java for Comparison

Tags: java, guava

I have a method which is supposed to compare a value with a list of values.

The compare function can be less than, greater than or equal to. I came across this `Predicate` concept which I am trying to understand and implement in this case. 
Below are my few questions.

1) There is `Predicate` class defined in apache commons, guava and javax.sql. What's the difference between them? (I tried going through docs but couldn't get it)

2) Is Guava predicate only meant to do filtering and not say a boolean function implementaion?

3) Can I get an example for the Predicate?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt in assuming that you submitted this before you finished typing it up

Comment: Guava has a `Predicate` interface, but it is meant for filtering.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You can implement a comparator using a (C++-style) predicate, where it's assumed that the predicate returns true iff `a < b`. e.g., `return less.apply(a, b) ? -1 : less.apply(b, a) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young In this case, should one `Predicate` return all the smaller, another return equal, and yet another return larger?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Rethinking on this, obviously you can't use `Predicate` directly because it's unary, but assuming there's a binary version, it's always assumed to return whether `a` is less than `b`. You simply swap the arguments to test the other direction. At least, that's how it's idiomatically done in C++.

Comment: @LPD Please read Guava Wiki pages ([FunctionalExplained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained)) before using Guava's functional idioms.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Due to some network issue I was not able to post my question properly. Updated the same.

Comment: What is the result of your operation? Compare the value and the list, then what?

Comment: and return `boolean` value

Comment: If what? All of them are greater, less than, equals? Which one?

Comment: That is what am trying to pass from outside to the function in the form of a predicate. Did I convey it properly?

Comment: I think I'm missing the point. Are you asking for a `Predicate`  implementation that will retrieve all values in the list that are `one of: [greater, smaller, or equal]` to your specified value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39087/discussion-between-lpd-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you want to test whether all elements of a given collection satisfy some condition, this is an example with guava's `Predicate` (@ColinD's comment points to a wealth of already existing predicates involving `Comparable`!):

```
public static class LessThan<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Predicate<T> {
  private final Comparable<T> value;

  public LessThan(final Comparable<T> value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean apply(final T input) {
    return value.compareTo(input) > 0;
  }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
  final Collection<Integer> things = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
  System.out.println(Iterables.all(things, new LessThan<Integer>(5)));
}
```

But unless you can reuse that predicate, you should consider a non-functional version as the guava wiki suggests, e.g. :

```
public static boolean allLessThan(Collection<Integer> numbers, Integer value) {
   for (Integer each : numbers) {
      if (each >= value) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I can use Iterables.any method and pass it a collection as well as a predicate which does my job. Would that be logical?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve? Returning to my example `LessThan` predicate - if you filter a collection through `any()` it will return true, if there is at least one element in the collection that satisfies the predicate, i.e. is less than the set value. See the [guava documentation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) for more options.

Comment: FYI, your `LessThan` predicate is equivalent to [Range.lessThan(C)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#lessThan(C)).

Comment: I knew that such a simple predicate should be provided by guava, thank you for pointing to the right place!

Answer (score 3):

In short, differences between Predicates are:

- `apache-commons`: is not generic;
- `guava`: is generic;
- `javax.sql.rowset`: is for use with `RowSet`s (for filtering SQL request results).

---

I believe that you want [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) not `Predicate`.

Answer (score 3):

I think Errandir got to the core of your problem: a predicate is a function from its input to a boolean, and you want to do tri-state comparison.

To answer your other questions though:

> Is Guava predicate only meant to do filtering and not say a boolean function implementation?

No.  A Guava predicate is a function that returns a boolean.
You can phrase most problems that are solved by predicates in terms of some kind of filtering, but they can be used without any collection that is being filtered.

> Can I get an example for the Predicate?

Here's a predicate that has uses independent of a collection:

```
Predicate<Person> isAuthorizedToBuyAlcohol = new Predicate<Person>() {
  public boolean apply(Person person) {
    return person.age() >= LEGAL_LIMIT;
  }
};
```

Comment: I can use `Iterables.any` method and pass it a collection as well as a predicate which does my job. Would that be logical?

Comment: @LPD, yep.  That's one way to check whether a collection contains something that satisfies a constraint.